# I need some help understanding this ntpq output, if it indicates proper GPS sync with PPS

Tags: javascript, gps, ntp, nmea

I've created a project (https://github.com/kshetline/aw-clock) that, among many other things, detects GPS time sync with PPS by examining the output from the `ntpq` command. What I'm expecting is output that looks like this:

```
pi@clock:~ $ ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 0.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.001
 1.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.001
 2.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.001
 3.debian.pool.n .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000   +0.000   0.001
*SHM(2)          .PPS.            0 l    9   64  377    0.000   -0.007   0.001
xSHM(0)          .GPS.            0 l   10   64  377    0.000  -586.75  58.377
-eterna.binary.n 128.138.140.44   2 u   79  128  377   62.565   +2.244   4.420
+t2.time.bf1.yah 98.139.133.62    2 u   53   64  377   28.750   +3.667  10.354
-65-100-46-164.d .SOCK.           1 u    3   64  377   88.300   +3.213   9.568
+time-ewr.0xt.ca 17.253.14.251    2 u   11   64  377   19.489   +2.813  12.572
```

For my own purposes, checking for the line with both SHM and PPS with the following regex has been working fine for me:

`/^\*SHM\b.+\.PPS\.\s+0\s+l\s+.+?\s([-+]?[.\d]+)\s+[.\d]+\s*$/`

One of the users of my project says he has GPS sync, but my code isn't detecting it. He's not sure about PPS sync. His output from `ntpq` looks like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ntpq -p
remote refid st t when poll reach delay offset jitter
==============================================================================
0.debian.pool.n .POOL. 16 p - 64 0 0.000 +0.000 0.001
oPPS(0) .PPS. 0 l 7 16 377 0.000 -290.00 0.321
*SHM(0) .GPS. 1 l 4 16 377 0.000 +4.782 4.952
SHM(2) .SHM2. 0 l - 16 0 0.000 +0.000 0.000
time.skylineser 130.207.244.240 2 u 50 64 1 37.196 -285.61 0.322
+ntp1.ring-u.net 130.207.244.240 2 u 49 64 1 28.878 -280.98 1.622
+50-205-244-108- 50.205.244.27 2 u 47 64 1 27.833 -287.90 3.220
sonic.boom.net 128.9.176.30 2 u 57 64 1 71.871 -284.30 0.001
```

I can't find sufficient documentation for `ntpq` to explain how this output works thoroughly enough for me to understand whether this output indicates proper PPS sync, just in a different way than it shows up for me, or if this indicates a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The user output is actually the same as yours just without/broken formatting.

It looks like the `PPS` offset is rather large so I wonder if they have everything configured correctly. They also have an `SHM(2)` entry which appears to be doing nothing. I wonder if there shared memory config is correct. My input sources list as;

NMEA GPS:
`xSHM(0)  .GPS.  0 l    3   16  377    0.000  -116.89  24.632`

PPS:
`*SHM(1)  .PPS.  0 l    6   16  377    0.000   -0.014   0.045`

The docs for `ntpq` can be found [here](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/ntpq.html). And the part that explains the status flags can be found [here](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/ntp/html/decode.html#peer).

Extract from the docs;

> ```
>   discarded as not valid
> x discarded by intersection algorithm
> . discarded by table overflow (not used)
> - discarded by the cluster algorithm
> + included by the combine algorithm
> # backup (more than tos maxclock sources)
> * system peer
> o PPS peer (when the prefer peer is valid)
> ```

I'd be curious to see there actual `ntp.conf` I wonder if they have a odd or specific setup. At a quick glance I'd say there actually using the `GPS/NMEA` as the system peer rather than the `PPS` I run several production S1 servers and haven't had a situation where the `PPS` is marked with the `o`

I'm also guessing when they sent you through that output the server had not been running long (or a least not had much connectivity) as the reachability of the remote IP servers is only `2` and given there polling every `64` sec I'd say there not reachable or don't like high frequency polls.

Ideally they need to leave it running for a while (at least till everything has a reach of 377) then look again. If they have the full `ntpq` suite then get the output from `ntpq -pcrv` and it will provide deeper details.

Comment: I wasn't thrown off by the formatting, only by the `oPPS(0) .PPS.` (with a big offset) vs "`SHM(2) .PPS.`. It seems like the user did have a configuration error, and after redoing their set-up got the same results as I did. My main concern was if my software needed to look for different, but also valid, ntpq output. So far it looks like the answer is no.

Comment: Ahh no worries.. remember that pps may not always be there and users might fall back to another method of sync